# jQuery inside each loop meteor not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

i everyone,

i have a problem that has already happened to me in another case, but I present this hoping that we can solve it:

The jquery (called on "rendered") works well when it is not generated by eachloop ... why not work in generated html?

i click on an image generated by eachloop and nothing happens

**gallery.html**

```
    {{#each gallery}}
        <div class="superbox-list">
            <img src="images/superbox/superbox-thumb-1.jpg" data-img="images/superbox/superbox-full-1.jpg" alt="My first photoshop layer mask on a high end PSD template theme" title="Miller Cine" class="superbox-img">
        </div>
    {{/each}}
        <div class="superbox-list">
            <img src="images/superbox/superbox-thumb-1.jpg" data-img="images/superbox/superbox-full-1.jpg" alt="My first photoshop layer mask on a high end PSD template theme" title="Miller Cine" class="superbox-img">
        </div>
        <div class="superbox-list">
            <img src="images/superbox/superbox-thumb-2.jpg" data-img="images/superbox/superbox-full-2.jpg" alt="My first photoshop layer mask on a high end PSD template theme" title="Bridge of Edgen" class="superbox-img">
        </div>
```

**gallery.js**

```
Template.gallery.rendered = function(){
    $('.superbox').SuperBox();
}

Template.gallery.helpers({
    gallery: function(){
        return Gallery.find();
    }
});
```

Example, 
[Image 1](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OKtKLzmnCXA/U7Q783W3QzI/AAAAAAAAH4U/I6WBLJigo8Q/s1600/Untitled-2.jpg)  [Image 2](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-WRRPofVjF88/U7Q9Nh1T23I/AAAAAAAAH4c/Uufs9Ou1lqs/s400/Untitled-4.jpg)

best regards,
ty

**EDIT:**

**I used this way and it worked,** although not find the method defer in meteor docs!

```
_.defer(function () {
  $('.superbox').SuperBox();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you got all the documents in `Gallery` when the template is created?

Comment: shouldn't it be $('.superbox-list') instead of $('.superbox') in your rendered?

Comment: Peppe: yes, i have all documents in Gallery, such is possivel see in Image 1.

Dave: I think this is not the problem because out of # each jquery works well.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is *probably* that the data isn't there when your gallery is first rendered. You can fix that by waiting on the subscription using iron-router's `waitOn` (if you're using iron-router) but that only solves the problem of the documents that are in the database on page load. Any new documents wouldn't be "superBox'd" either. So the way around that is to have a specific template for each Gallery row.
Your each becomes:

```
{{#each gallery}}
    {{> galley_row }}
{{/each}}
```

You add a new template:

```
<template name="gallery_row">
    <div class="superbox-list">
        <img src="images/superbox/superbox-thumb-1.jpg" data-img="images/superbox/superbox-full-1.jpg" alt="My first photoshop layer mask on a high end PSD template theme" title="Miller Cine" class="superbox-img">
    </div>
</template>
```

Then whenever your new template is rendered (each iteration of the #each loop):

```
Template.galley_row.rendered = function () {
    $('.superbox').SuperBox();
});
```

Comment: I tried to do it that way, but I was not successful. The Jquery not reacts.

Comment: try my revised rendered, I removed the ```this.$('.superbox-list')``` and replaced it with ```$('.superbox')```

Answer (score 0):

**I used this way and it worked,** although not find the method defer in meteor docs!

```
_.defer(function () {
  $('.superbox').SuperBox();
});
```

Comment: That's an [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) method, not a Meteor method. Not Meteor's job to document underscore! This still has a problem, if you load the page then add a new Gallery object to the database it will show up but not be "superboxed".