# Using Jquery in Meteorjs

Tags: jquery, meteor

I just getting started with meteor so I want to use append function in jquery but it not append anything

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {      
Meteor.startup(function() {
        $( "span" ).append('Hello');
      });
```

I get no errors and nothing happens or appending.

HTML:

```
<span>lorem ipsum</span>
<p>stackoverflow</p>
```

i think the problem is `$('span').append('Hello');` it loading before the html code ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Meteor needs to use its renderer's own hooks for "DOM readiness". If you use Blaze (Meteor's default renderer, as of now) you can use the `Template.templateName.onRendered()` function for this:

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function () {
  $( "span" ).append('Hello');
});
```

This will append "Hello" to any span the template `templateName` may contain.

Note that, as I implied earlier, this will be different depending on the renderer you choose for your app: Blaze, Angular or React. (or anything else for that matter) But the default one is Blaze, so if you do not know which one you are using, it is probably Blaze.

Comment: Hi again, well your solutions it work but **somtimes** when I restart the server it not append anything ?? did you know why ?

Comment: Well, what template did you assign your jquery command to? Does this template always contain a span first-hand? As in: it is clearly written within the template's html code, and not between handlebar statements such as `{{#each}}`?

Comment: well Im using iron router, so i have a layout template ( `{{> yield}}` ) and another one `foo` and the span element it exist `foo` template so i put `Template.layout.onRendered`.... ( i do Template.foo.onRendered but it not ork at all )

Comment: Yeah there is a `{{#each}}` in foo temaplate

Comment: Then if the span is in the `each`, try creating another template for the inside and use `onRendered` on this new sub-template (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24540816/1439597))

Comment: Fixed thanx, I already use this solutions, but it was appended tree times because i have tree `span` , and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539364/jquery-inside-each-loop-meteor-not-works/24540816#24540816) i use `this.$('span)` and i solve it, thanks again